# Collecting inner List from outer List using Java 8

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

Let be Parent is a java class which contains normal
primitive variables and an inner List and its corresponding getters and setters.
Parent has a method getValue(index) which will return the list
or field(corresponding getters).

Now I will get a  List and to find out inner-inner-inner List. (3 level hierarchy).
 I will get the indexes from outside and I want to return innermost list.

Method:-

```
List<Parent> getList(int[] indexes, Parent parent)
 {

 int first = indexes[0];
 int second = indexes[1];
 int third = indexes[2];

 // Now I get the first inner List<Parent> by this code. 
 List<Parent> inner = (List<Parent>)  parent.getValue(first);

 // How will I get the remaining two lists from 'inner'
 }
```

How can I write the code in Java 8 using Lamdas and Streams.

Comment: You want to navigate a tree-like structure? That doesn't seem to be a good place to use streams. A loop would be better (but there would be only 2 iterations, so it's questionable if you even need a loop).

Comment: @fabian: I can't get you. Can u explain with code.

Comment: I probably didn't read the question thouroughly enough. However using streams would be counterproductive. Forget the loops. Why don't you use `parent.getValue(indexes[0]).get(indexes[1]).getValue(indexes[2])` (maybe with some additional casts)?

Comment: we cannot call get() because inner List<Parent> contains inner-inner List in its all elements.

Comment: OK, I don't really get it. Please improve the description of the data structure and add example(s) of input+expected output.